# How to transform an HTML fragment to another HTML fragment?

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsoup, sanitization

I have a browser editor, of type `contentEditable` where users can copy/paste or select html fragments to put inside.

These fragments can be any kind of HTML, so we must sanitize the content so that it does not contain some security issue tags (like `<script>` etc...).

I know some sanitizer libraries that allow some Whitelist policy (like JSoup on the JVM), but these rules are generally very simple, like saying which tags/attributes are whitelisted and nothing else.

We want more advanced rules like:

- Define which inline styles to keep or not,
- Transform relative links to absolute links
- Blacklist or whitelist some tags according to their className
- Allow some URI attributes according to the URI pattern (like allowing only links to a certain domain).
- In some cases we want forbidden dom nodes to be "replaced" by their childs (to remove formatting and html layout elements, but not to loose the text nodes that were in the blacklisted tags

So far we have done some code to handle this but I find this very hacky. Is there a known library, standard or algorithm to handle such things? I'm not an XML parse/transform expert, anything I could use like XSLT, SAX or something else that could help me solve my problem.

I'm looking for solutions on both the browser (JS) and the JVM (Java or Scala). Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried [OWASP Java HTML Sanitizer](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_HTML_Sanitizer_Project#tab=Main)? I don't but it seems highly configurable and it is open source. Found at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_sanitization) in "HTML sanitization" entry. Hope it helps.

Comment: yes @fonkap but the `ElementPolicy` does not permit to handle most of my usecases :( https://code.google.com/p/owasp-java-html-sanitizer/

Comment: Oh I see, `ElementPolicy.apply` only takes the name and the attributes of the tag. This clearly is not enough to write complex cases... I'm very sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Showdown.js can help you?  https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown

Comment: Seems i was a bit too quick here to answer. Showdown.js won't do you any good. Since there doesn't seem to be a good known library, a better solution would be to use a HTML5 form where you can write your own validation?